# How can I avoid to trigger the applyDrilldown Function in Highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have build my own drilldown behaviour but I get a Javascript Error in the Chart.prototype.applyDrilldown function when I press on the text under the stacked chart instead of the column. How is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Here the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dfvn9JnvQu2dv4s7Jn7Q?p=info

regards

PS.: In my real project the event is triggered series.length times. I can not reproduce this in plunkr. Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: Do you mean error when you click on the xAxis label ?

Comment: Yes, the link of the xAxis.

Comment: It is known bug, related topic: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3197